# A class object to another datatype?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Can you convert a class object to for example to int, double, char etc.. is it called implicit or explicit conversion?

```
class MyClass
{
int x;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass MyObject; //convert my object to int
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a casting operator:

```
class Foo {
public:
    operator int() const { return 1; }
};

class Bar {
public:
    operator Foo() const { return Foo(); }
};


int main() {
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    int i1 = f; // implicit, just one conversion
    int i2 = b; // not valid
    int i3 =  static_cast<Foo>(b); // Convert b to Foo explicitly, Foo to int implicitly
}
```

Comment: Not sure but can you use explicit casts?

Comment: Yes, both implicit and explicit.

Comment: @user: This would allow an *implicit* conversion from `Foo` to `int`. There is no way to make an explicit conversion operator in C++03; in C++0x we can mark the function as `explicit`.

Comment: @GMan: And that's about time. `explicit` has been lacking for a long time :P

Comment: When do you required a static_cast if int i = f can do the conversion?

Comment: When more than one conversion is needed - e.g. `Bar -> Foo -> int`

Answer (score 0):

A constructor can also function as a cast operator going the other way.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const Bar &)   // Bar -> Foo
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(const Foo &)
};
```